# Any Advantage of SqlEntityConnection over SqlDataConnection?

Tags: f#, type-providers

Starting with an existing SQL Server database and no EF model, is there any reason to favor the SqlEntityConnection type provider over SqlDataConnection?

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to newer versions of Entity Framework while still using SqlEntityConnection. This allows you to take advantage of bug fixes and performance improvements. There will never be a newer version of LINQ-to-SQL, which powers SqlDataConnection. For me, that's reason enough to prefer SqlEntityConnection.

Answer (score 0):

One reason you might want to use EF is for its finer-grained control on lazy-loading of results. For example you can use the `Include` method to make a given query eagerly load a specified set of nested values. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is more detail on this.